# how to build html navigation bar dynamically using data from database

Tags: c#, xml, linq, recursion

I have this data from database with self relation

```
 Parent_ID     Name           Child_ID
 1             cities         null
 2             Egypt          1
 3             Saudi          1
 4             technology     null
 5             vb.net         4
 6             c#             4
```

Now i want to build html navigation bar using this data

To be like the following

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">cities</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Egypt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Saudi</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">technology</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">vb.net</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">c#</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't know what is the best way to da that 
My be xml node or my be using linqu ...
Whatever the best way help me please.

Comment: do you have any code so far? do you need help connecting to the database or formatting the dataset returned?

Comment: do you have an mvc website?

Comment: no i haven't any code but i just think to solve this problem need to use recursive function to rearrange parent and child to get this navigation bar format

Comment: yes i will do that on an mvc website

Comment: yes, i understand hang on a sec ill knock up an example

Comment: i think it's very cool but it's hard on me i need more easy solution using simple recursion function like for example fill_treeview function in windows app

Comment: hmm well ive done this exact task many times at large companies. Obvs ive simlified it a bit here but I find having the single list by far the most simple and performant solution. you do have recursion in your razor views

Answer (score 0):

you can use `asp:reapeater` control provide datasource to it and give html format inside it. The easiest and the efficient way.

Explore it more....

Edited: **You must mention**

in mvc, you can pass data inside `viewBag`, `viewdata` whatever you like and on view you can use foreach iteration and inside it generate the required html

like

`ViewDate["data whatever"] = your data`

and on html

```
@foreach(var item in ....)
{
  <a href='item.whatever Value'>
}
```

Comment: i'am using mvc5 so that i can't use asp:reapeater

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is one method of creating a n deep menu viewmodel

grab all the data from the table with one select and populate a list of menuItemMVs. create a menuMV object and put this list in the static AllMenuItems list. create a razor view for the root of the menu and bind it to menuMV. create a partial view for a menu item which binds to menuItemVM this should contain a for loop looping through the childern and recursively calling RenderParital itself (the partial view) for each child in the menuItemVM it is rendering.

get your root menu razor to loop over the rootMenuItems and renderpartial your menuitem partial view for each

```
    public class menuVM
    {
        public static List<menuItemVM> AllMenuItems { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<menuItemVM> rootMenuitems
        {
            get { return menuVM.AllMenuItems.Where(c => c.ParentId == null); }
        }
    }

    public class menuItemVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get;set; }

        public IEnumerable<menuItemVM> Childern {
            get
            {
                return menuVM.Childern.Where(c => c.ParentId == this.Id);
            }
        }
    }
```

> ps. I think you have childId and parentId the wrong way around in your
>   sample data